# bash script not giving the MariaDB service status correctly

Tags: bash, shell, centos, mariadb, centos7

I have to check my MariaDB Service is running or not in CentOS 7.

For this I just create the .sh file. Content of this file is below

```
#!/bin/bash
service=mariadb

if ( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 )
then
  echo "$service is running!!!"
else
  echo "$service is not running!!!"
fi
```

when I run the following command

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep mariadb | wc -l
```

If service is running return 1

If service is stop return 0

above output is correct.

But when I `execute my .sh file` it gives the wrong output

If service is running return (mariadb is not running!!!)

If service is stop return (mariadb is not running!!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(` is for creating a subshell, and is probably not really what you want here.  You could do

```
if [ $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep "$service" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then
```

but really this would be much easier with `pgrep` instead of building your own pipeline to find the process.  Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
service=mariadb

if pgrep -f "$service"
then
    printf '%s is running!!!' "$service"
else
    printf '%s is not running!!!' "$service"
fi
```

`pgrep` will exit with `0`, which is success when it's an exit status, if it finds something, or `1` if it does not find any matching processes.

Also, I switched to `printf` instead of `echo`.  It shouldn't be a problem with this example, but `echo` [isn't the preferred way most of the time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

In your attempt with the parenthesis, you're trying to use `>` as a greater-than comparison, but it will actually be consumed by the shell as a redirection operator (I bet you have a file called `0` in that directory now).  If you want to do arithmetic stuff you need double parens `((...))` or, if you want to test things you can use the square brackets as I did above.  The single parenthesis means to run the contained commands in a subshell though.

Comment: Like this service=mariadb
if($(pgrep -f "$service")>0)
then
  echo "$service is running!!!"
else
  echo "$service is not running!!!"
fi

Comment: @user3441151 You still don't want the parens in your `if` condition, and you don't need to test for `>0`, let its exit status do the work for you, and `if` already knows how to interpret it (just as my example takes advantage of)